# How to convert 'set of char' to 'set of byte' in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I am new to Delphi. I was trying to compile a sample code using RAD studio and I get a compiler error saying incompatible types. And i see that, the code is trying to assign a variable of type `set of Char` to another variable of type `set of Byte`.

```pascal
Values := ABC.allowedValues;
```

Here `Values` is of type `set of Byte` and `allowedValues` is of type `set of Char`.

I could not find a way to do the above conversion.

Comment: Which Delphi version?

Comment: How would you want the conversion to handle char members that don't fit into byte? Remember that char is 2 bytes in size.

Comment: I am using  Delphi 10.4 sydney and 10.3 Rio and Enterprise edition

Comment: Please show complete sample code so we have some context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very likely (like "almost certainly"), the best solution is to redesign the code. Something is probably not done in the most appropriate way if you do need to do this.

Also, if you are using a new Delphi version (2009 or newer), `Char` is a two-byte Unicode character, and so there is no such thing as a "true" `set of Char`, because the base type of a [Delphi set](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Sets) must be an ordinal type with at most 256 distinct values. (Two bytes implies 65 536 distinct values.)

Before Delphi 2009, however, `Char` was indeed a single-byte character; under the hood it was simply a `Byte`. Today, `Char = WideChar` while `AnsiChar` is the old one-byte character type.

So let us assume that you are either using a pre-Unicode Delphi version or that you are actually working with `set of AnsiChar`. If you write `set of Char` in a modern Delphi version, the compiler will "helpfully" interpret that as `set of AnsiChar` and give you a [warning](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/W1050_WideChar_reduced_to_byte_char_in_set_expressions_(Delphi)).

A "slow" but truly type-safe approach to performing the conversion is as follows:

```pascal
type
  TCharSet = set of AnsiChar;
  TByteSet = set of Byte;

function SetConvert(ACharSet: TCharSet): TByteSet;
begin
  Result := [];
  for var c in ACharSet do
    Include(Result, Ord(c))
end;
```

This makes use of inline variables introduced in Delphi 10.3 and `for..in` loops introduced in Delphi 2005 (?). Pre-10.3, you need to write

```pascal
function SetConvert(ACharSet: TCharSet): TByteSet;
var
  c: AnsiChar;
begin
  Result := [];
  for c in ACharSet do
    Include(Result, Ord(c))
end;
```

Finally, your question is strictly speaking not well defined, since you don't specify *how* you want to map character sets into byte sets. Above, I assume that you want to use the mapping induced by the `Ord/Chr` mapping between the base types.

Comment: There is also a "fast" way which however is not as type safe. Since performance is very likely not an issue here, I think I'll skip it.

Answer (score 0):

Variante A:

```
uses
  System.SysUtils;

type
  TCharSet = set of AnsiChar;
  TByteSet = set of Byte;

  TMySet=packed record
   case char of
     'A': (a : TCharSet);
     'B': (b : TByteSet);
   end;

 var
  x: TMySet;
  i: integer;
begin
  try
    x.a := ['a', 'z', 'A'..'Z'];
    for i in x.b do
     write(i, ', ');

 except
   on E: Exception do
     Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
 end;
```

end.

Variante B:

```
uses
  System.SysUtils;

type
  TCharSet = set of AnsiChar;
  TByteSet = set of Byte;

var
  a: TCharSet;
  b: TByteSet absolute a;
  i: integer;
begin
  try
    a := ['a', 'z', 'A'..'Z'];
    for i in b do
      write(i, ', ');
  except
   on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```